# Output the weights from a Pytorch model

Tags: model, reinforcement-learning

Here a very basic model :

```
class LinearDeepQNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lr, n_actions, input_dims):
        super(LinearDeepQNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions)

        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
        self.device = T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.to(self.device)

    def forward(self, state):
        layer1 = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        actions = self.fc2(layer1)

        return actions
```

Be aware that I am using `Pytorch`, not `Keras` or `Tensorflow`. In my `Agent()` class, I instantiate `self.Q_eval = LinearDeepQNetwork(self.lr, self.n_actions, self.input_dims)`. Once I have trained my agent for several episodes, I need to output the weights of `self.Q_eval`. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch: Extract learned weights correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734327/pytorch-extract-learned-weights-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to inject the weights from `Q_eval` network to `Q_next` network. I made the following function :

```
def replace_target_network(self):
        self.Q_next.load_state_dict(self.Q_eval.state_dict())
        self.Q_next.eval()
```

**Answer** I can get the weights with `Q_eval.state_dict()`.