# Load pytorch model from .pts file

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am wondering if someone can explain how to load a pytorch model saved with the .pts extension and extract the weights from the file?

More specifically, I am able to load the model using:

```
model = torch.jit.load(model_path.pts,torch.device("cuda"))
```

which is of the following type:

```
torch.jit._script.RecursiveScriptModule
```

and I have looked at the following:
https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/doxygen/pytorch/classtorch_1_1jit_1_1__script_1_1RecursiveScriptModule.html

I can make forward passes with this but trying to figure out how to get the weights so I can also perform updates on the weights.

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734327/pytorch-extract-learned-weights-correctly

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer ah yes silly me lol model.parameters() sorry :)

Comment: It's alright, no problem,  :D