# Initalize using previous .pth and train for further epochs in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

How do I initialize a UNet model from its previous weights and further train the model for more epochs?

This is current model and after training I am saving the state_dict() as .pth file

```
class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UNet,self).__init__()
        # encoder 
        
        self.max_pool_2x2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2)
        self.down_conv_1 = double_conv(3,64)
        self.down_conv_2 = double_conv(64,128)
        self.down_conv_3 = double_conv(128,256)
        self.down_conv_4 = double_conv(256,512)
        self.down_conv_5 = double_conv(512,1024)
        
        # decoder

        self.up_trans_1= nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024,
                                            out_channels=512,
                                            kernel_size=2,
                                            stride=2)

        self.up_conv_1 = double_conv(1024,512)

        self.up_trans_2= nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512,
                                            out_channels=256,
                                            kernel_size=2,
                                            stride=2)

        self.up_conv_2 = double_conv(512,256)

        self.up_trans_3= nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256,
                                            out_channels=128,
                                            kernel_size=2,
                                            stride=2)

        self.up_conv_3 = double_conv(256,128)

        self.up_trans_4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128,
                                            out_channels=64,
                                            kernel_size=2,
                                            stride=2)

        self.up_conv_4 = double_conv(128,64)
        
        self.out = nn.Conv2d(64,1,kernel_size=1)


    def forward(self, image):
       ##code for forward prop

        

model=UNet()
model.cuda()
# y= model(image)


# model.train()
# optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.1, momentum=0.9)
```

Now I want to initialize the same model with that .pth file and train further?

Comment: Does this solves your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734327/pytorch-extract-learned-weights-correctly

Comment: See https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Answer (score 0):

```
state= torch.load("/content/model_WandB_12.pth")
model.load_state_dict(state)
```

used this to load the model and
then run the training loop